# Weblogic Starting Configuration Wizard Failed With Error: "=="" was unexpected at this time

Tags: weblogic12c

I am trying to create a Domain in Weblogic server 12c.
While executing the script ***config.cmd*** at the path

`C:\Oracle\Middleware12c\oracle_common\common\bin` getting the error as "==" was unexpected at this time.

Have set JDK path while installing the weblogic server as below

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;%PATH%
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
```

Weblogic server is installed properly.

Comment: Display your PATH env var before starting the configuration wizard and check that the value is not enclosed with double quotes.

Comment: Thank you @EmmanuelCollin, solved the issue some path had double quotes when I removed it it started working .

Comment: Great, can you accept my answer plz.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display your PATH env var before starting the configuration wizard and check that the value is not enclosed with double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have resolved this error by following steps

open the command line 
echo %path%
then you can see all path variables 
copy the result string into a notepad , then you can notice there are " characters 
next remove those.


open the command line in the fmw_14.1.1.0.0_wls_lite_generic.jar folder 
set path=double_quote_emoved_pathvariable
java -jar fmw_14.1.1.0.0_wls_lite_generic.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open the command line 
echo %path%
then you can see all path variables 
copy the result string into a notepad , then you can notice there are " characters 
next remove those.

open the command line in the fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar folder 
set path=double_quote_emoved_pathvariable
java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar
```